# Azure app service website recycles after staging/production swap

Tags: azure-web-app-service

After a staging/producion swap our production website recycles. It seems to happen between 30 minutes and 6 hours and only occurs once.

Is it possible to swap 2 deployment slots without having the application recycle in the production environment?

This is how we do the swap

1. Deploy our website
2. Invoke-AzureRMResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots -ResourceName $websiteName/$sourceSlot -Action applySlotConfig -Parameters $ParametersObject -Force (changes the appsettings)
3. Invoke-AzureRMResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots -ResourceName $websiteName/$sourceSlot -Action slotsswap -Parameters $ParametersObject -Force (virtual ip swap)

We have also tried to restart the website before we did the virtual ip swap, but with the same result.

Comment: Duplicate of https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ee6e880-80a9-4ea8-a2c8-220573225321/azure-app-service-website-recycles-after-stagingproduction-swap?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview. Please avoid posting same questions in two places without cross reference, as it leads to duplicate investigations.

Comment: I know there is a recycle immediately after the swap if you use slot-specific settings - which most people do. Did you try eliminating those?

Comment: @John are you sure abt recycle AFTER the swap? My understanding is there is a restart BEFORE the swap to get the latest settings in.

Comment: @aljj Well, yes, of course you're right.

Comment: @john I don't have any slot specific settings, so that should not be the problem

Comment: I've added some logging to Global.asax Application_Start and Application_End and it seems that Application_Start that is called again between 30 minutes and 6 hours after the swap. Application_End is not called. Shouldn't Application_Start only be called once for the first request to the application?

Comment: @KasperNørtoft Yes. And you are sure it doesn't go down on the swap itself? It doesn't log anything you have in `Application_End`?

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, it does restart 30mins after the swap? 
Sounds unrelated to the swap/deployment. Have you check the logs? eventlog.xml?
try to add alerts on interesting metrics

hth,
Aldo

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is related to the swap as we don't have any problems if we deploy directly to the production slot

Comment: I have checked the Audit log in Azure and the eventlog.xml, but nothing related in there